# Problemas con routing en Angular, porque no me trae la informacion del link al hacer clic en libros?

Tags: angular, api, rutas

Muy buenos dia comunidad, estoy intentando traerme la informacion de un libro al hacer clic en una lista de libros, la lista la veo perfectamente lo que me da a entender que el id de cada libro esta siendo leido, pero al hacer clic en algun link de un libro listado no me hace nada, al ver la consola veo el siguiente error:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'books/OL26757374M'
```

y creo que es algun error con la ruta, lo supongo porque el link deberia ser algo como asi(cuando lo hago en mi navegado pues me trae el json con la informacion que me gustaria filtrar):

```
https://the-books--goncalomatos2.repl.co/books?id=OL26757374M
```

la cosa es que si en mi codigo coloco en la ruta el simbolo ? entonces el error sigue siendo lo mismo pero en la ruta me coloca %23, estos son los **segmentos de codigo** de las rutas tal como las defino y las llamo en mis componentes:

```
 app-routing-module.ts
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'books?id=', component: BookSelectComponent},
      { path: 'books', component: BookListComponent },
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'books'}
    ];

book-list-component.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'books?id=', component: BookSelectComponent},
  { path: 'books', component: BookListComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'books'}
];

book-select-component.ts
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const id= Number.parseInt(params.get('id'), 10);

      this.api.getBook(id).subscribe(book => {
        this.title = book.title;

      })
    })
  }
```

y asi esta en mi api-service.ts

```
  getBook(id: number): Observable<Book> {
    if (this.booksCache[id]) {
      return of(this.booksCache[id]);
    }

    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/books/${id}`).pipe(
      map<any, Book>(book => this._adaptBookFromServe(book))
    );
  }
```

Si pueden indicarme cual es el error y que deberia hacer, seria optimo, muy agradecido de antemano

Comment: solo para aclarar estoy leyendo desde local host porque tengo un servidor backend para simular el link

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero en tu ruta debes definir que recibirás un variable en angular algo como esto:

```
 { path: 'books?id=:id', component: BookSelectComponent},
```

ahora el valor lo debes buscar en `params` de la siguiente manera:

```
const id= params.id
```

Answer (score 0):

lo solucione de la siguiente forma:
En el routing:

```
{ path: 'books/:id', component: BookSelectComponent},
```

y en el service:

```
      return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/books?id=${id}`).pipe(
      map<any, Book>(book => this._adaptBookFromServe(book)),
      );
```